# How can I create Java NIO 'Path' object with a URI which has fragment?

Tags: java, path, uri, nio

How can I create Java NIO 'Path' object using a URI which has fragment.

The following code throws IllegalArgumentException,

```
java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(new URI("file:/home/test#glacier"));
```

Exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a fragment component
at sun.nio.fs.UnixUriUtils.fromUri(UnixUriUtils.java:55)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.getPath(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:98)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:138)
```

Comment: So after the `file:/` part you want to parse the path and insert the full path?

Comment: And what does the `#` mean?

Comment: # means there is a fragment in the path just after the same symbol.

Comment: So you want to go to the file:/...../home/test/........./glacier directory? And you're not sure how to complete it?

Comment: Or is it file:/home/test/....../glacier ?

Comment: It should be a file '/home/test' and a fragment 'glacier' (may be used by the file, not sure). But what I understand is java.nio.file.Path doesn't support fragments in URI so I just done a work arround to skip the error
   `uri = uri.getFragment() == null ? uri : new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getSchemeSpecificPart(), null);`
This will create the file, '/home/test', with out a fragment.